# ssh to remote server gives incorrect hostname

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins

Below piece of code is part of my build script & I'm running it from Jenkins as a parameterized build option(node).

It is able to connect to server_b and does the tasks as expected, but the only command not working is the "hostname -f".

It still gives the server_a's hostname value instead of server_b's hostname value.

I'm not sure what exactly I'm doing incorrectly,thanks.

```
#!/bin/bash

server_b(){

 folder="/home/mylogin/server_b"
 ssh -tt myuser@server_b.com << EOF
  echo "$(hostname -f)" ## tried echo `hostname -f` as well
  cd $folder 
  echo -e "FOLDER: $folder"
  <other commands that works fine>
  exit 
EOF
}


server_b
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try escaping the $ that you want interpreted on the remote machine, eg :

```
echo \$(hostname -f)
```